# How to Run test groups from command line

Tags: testng

I need to run specific test groups in a Test Class ...When I ran with -Dtest=**test classname**  -Dgroups=**testgroupname** it didnt work neither if I use just -Dgroups ..I am running this from command line ...

Comment: ...and what tool/programming language are you using?

Comment: When you say didn't work - what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using

```
java org.testng.TestNG -testclass org.nv.testclassname -groups yourgroupname
```

Refer [Running TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng) for more options.

Comment: Thank you for the response ....I think I was not clear enough ...I do have maven and would like to run the tests using mvn clean install ..I tried mvn clean install -Dgroups=groupname test ..I have a class myClass where certain methods are marked by one group and others are by different group name ..When I run the above command it starts running methods not even in this class and doesnt have this group name ...If I do mvn clean install -Dtest=TestClassName all the test methods in that class does run ...For running groups my question is just the -Dgroups= is enuf and any issue with cmd sytax

Comment: You cannot have just groups.  You would have to add package. You can use it with regex patterns to specify packages.